# List.Aggregate unexpected result

Tags: .net, string, list, aggregate

When I run this code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("a");
list.Add("b");
list.Add("c");
list.Add("d");

string s = list.Aggregate((total, item) => total += item + ",");
```

I expect s to be:

```
a,b,c,d,
```

but instead, s is:

```
ab,c,d,
```

can anyone tell me why it's not appending a comma between the first and second index?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find that this works

```
string s = list.Aggregate(string.Empty, (total, item) => total += item + ",");
```

You can see why if you test this:

```
var total = "a";
var item = "b";
var s = total += item + ",";
```

This results in "ab,"

Using an initial empty seed value for total (either (string)null or string.Empty) will give you the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

The following overload of Aggregate will work:

```
string s = list.Aggregate<string, string>(null, (total, item) => total + item + ",");
```

Basically, the version you're using puts the "a" as the value of `total` as the initial condition, then appends the rest on using the supplied lambda. My version starts the total out with `null` and then appends each item on.

Comment: This being said, I like Phil's version better.

Answer (score 1):

Tried and works

```
string s = list.Aggregate((total, item) => total += "," + item);
```

The problem is: When the runtime calls Aggregate Func for the first time `total` is "a" and item is "b". Really this extensions was designed to perform calcs not to concatenate strings.

However take note that the resulting string is a,b,c,d (without the ending comma) I don't know if this is preferable or not (depends on your use of the resulting string)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I actually used your method in my code, but felt I had to give the checkmark to phil since my original question did say I was expecting the result string to end in a comma.  (Even though for my project I didn't actually want it to end in a comma)

Comment: @Matt I imagined that this was your requirement, but I agree with your choice. Thanks anyway